# Getting xml data stored in a varchar out of SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

We have a simple table (an audit log) that our (3rd-party) product fills with data.  The problem is that the data appears to be an XML serialisation of data, stored in a `varchar(max())` column.

```
CREATE TABLE Audit (
    AuditID int IDENTITY, 
    AuditData nvarchar(max) NULL
)
```

The data AuditData then looks a bit like this:

```
<DELETED customerId="89" 
    username="alice" 
    firstname="Alice" 
    lastname="WTF" 
    field1="..." 
    field2="..." 
    fieldn="..."
/>
```

Is there *any* sensible way of getting at this data from SQL queries?  For example let us say I want to get all audit records where the customerId is 89.

I don't want to have to resort to string mangling if I can possibly help it!

```
-- This is bad:
SELECT AuditID, AuditData
FROM Audit 
WHERE AuditData LIKE '%customerId="89"%'
```

Comment: If the data is valid XML, you can easily convert it to the XML data type and query that way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that gave me the clue I needed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would easier/faster if `AuditData` was an XML column but you can cast it in the query.

```
select AuditID, AuditData
from Audit
where cast(AuditData as xml).value('(/DELETED/@customerId)[1]', 'int') = 89
```

`Note:` This requires that `AuditData` column contains valid XML for all rows in the table. (NULL is ok) and SQL Server 2005 or higher.

If you want to filter on `customerId` regardless of the root node name you can use this instead.

```
select AuditID, AuditData
from Audit
where cast(AuditData as xml).value('(/*/@customerId)[1]', 'int') = 89
```

Comment: If you do convert the column to the XML data type, and create XML indexes, the `value()` will not use them; in that case it would be more efficient to use the `exist()` method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx

Comment: That's perfect, thank you.  Unfortunately we can't change the data type of the column, as it's a 3rd-party database.  I can, however, add a view that means I don't need to do this again for this table.

Answer (score 0):

### Converting in XML will be much easier. Following scripts can help you to get your result.

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML

SET @MyXML = `<DELETED 
    customerId="89"    
    username="alice" 
    firstname="Alice" 
    lastname="WTF" 
    field1="..." 
    field2="..." 
    fieldn="..."
/>`
```

---

```
SELECT

a.b.value(`'@customerId'`,`'varchar(10)'`) AS customerId

FROM @MyXML.nodes(`'DELETED'`) a(b)
```

[Find More Things](http://sqlnetcode.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-read-xml-file-using-t-sql.html)

Comment: I don't need just one field from one record though.  This is 1000's of records, so I don't see how that's *simpler* than `SELECT RecordId, ModifiedDate, CAST(AuditValue as XML).value('(*/@username)[1]', 'varchar(50)') FROM Audit;`