# SQL Server 2000 - extract data from XML stored in VARCHAR

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Similar to [Getting xml data stored in a varchar out of SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254778/getting-xml-data-stored-in-a-varchar-out-of-sql) I need extract a value from an XML string stored in a `VARCHAR` column.

However, the data is on SQL Server 2000 and therefore the XML type cannot be used.

Is this possible in SQL Server 2000?

e.g. for the following XML, how can I select the values in the `<status>` nodes:

```
<entities>
    <entity>
        <name>foo</name>
        <status>1</status>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <name>bar</name>
        <status>2</status>
    </entity>
</entities>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
declare @xml varchar(1000)
SET @xml='<entities>
    <entity>
        <name>foo</name>
        <status>1</status>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <name>bar</name>
        <status>2</status>
    </entity>
</entities>'
select @xml,SUBSTRING(@xml,CHARINDEX('<status>',@xml)+LEN('<status>'),(CHARINDEX('</status>',@xml)-(CHARINDEX('<status>',@xml)+LEN('<status>'))))
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution I was just working through myself!

Comment: I think it should be `-LEN('<status>')` not `+LEN('<status>')` for the length param

Comment: it gives you the correct status tag value as i i have tested in my machine

Answer (score 1):

You could use [OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276847%28v=sql.80%29.aspx); it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt the example in the documentation to your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I think openxml is the best solution for your problem.

```
DECLARE @xml VARCHAR(2000)
SET @xml = N'
<entities>
    <entity>
        <name statue="1">foo</name>
        <status>1</status>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <name statue="2">bar</name>
        <status>2</status>
    </entity>
</entities>
'

DECLARE @docHandle int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @xml


SELECT *
   FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, N'/entities/entity',2)
WITH (name VARCHAR(20), status INT)
```

Comment: do I have to declare every node in the WITH () clause? There are many more in my real data than in this sample.

Comment: As far as I know you should mention the node names. This is same as defining fields in a table.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific - there are 9 nodes in the XML but I only want to extract 2 of them - do I need to declare all 9 or just the 2 I want?